# Is there a way to divide each component/element of my list by a value that corresponds to the level of some factor variable

Tags: r, list, loops, apply, metafor

I am currently having an issue with model convergence when running the `rma.mv` command in `metafor`. I have managed to figure out that it is because of erroneous code earlier on in my R script, which results in the calculated variances being very large (and erroneous). So, I'm at the point where I know the issue, but I do not know how to solve it. Below I will outline what I am trying to do, how I have currently achieved this and  how I isolated the cause of the issue:

#### What I am trying to do

The gist of what I am trying to do is to take bootstrapped SEE values for each predictive model in my dataset and scale these to the criterion mean for the corresponding study. (i.e., the actual value measured). It's worth noting that some studies have multiple models. The scaling is done as follows:

(SEE/criterion mean)*100.

#### Data

```
structure(list(Study = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), 
    Model = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
    "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"), class = "factor"), 
    Residual = c(1.585838423, 10.53555743, 10.67781267, 1.22720582, 
    2.598848981, 26.94888607, 1.440304678, 15.74086952, 24.27068334, 
    11.74554852, 13.21437544, 12.81558569, 15.65125984, 0.25625278, 
    7.941652407, 5.557930412, 5.359401505, 8.537299607, 2.671115348, 
    17.34002169, 2.598006397, 1.011493647, 10.38934426, 23.80005223, 
    5.655188679, 4.878735797, 11.28737632, 1.048913043, 6.670565717, 
    6.100551281, 15.55386342, 0.452170844, 1.077426851, 4.152827648, 
    13.16037736, 4.308822184, 3.383948815, 16.53474723, 5.323566515, 
    2.386768718, 5.63280155, 3.577780725, 1.60254086, 15.74086952, 
    0.490982433, 20.16709778, 4.622970061, 1.894674528, 14.60716285, 
    1.353952437, 4.596126567, 6.579200694, 2.749886696, 7.002473325, 
    6.999046711, 5.986306941, 15.80934315, 0.028470501, 8.299180328, 
    2.372475627, 9.538286164, 4.878735797, 6.671197129, 7.172826087, 
    0.19253775, 3.098225566, 14.50304585, 0.680903636, 15.64487166, 
    2.742369838, 11.42322707, 2.365470852, 1.838235294, 9.9, 
    1.470588235, 1.041666667, 0.454545455, 22.45614035, 6.196296296, 
    9.181818182, 31.97674419, 6.607142857, 7.720588235, 15.88888889, 
    14.09090909, 2.5, 1.875, 0, 7.75, 4.6875, 6.25, 14.8, 10.88235294, 
    0, 2.121212121, 0, 9.824074074, 9.181818182, 9.186046512, 
    13.03571429, 0, 5.333333333, 13, 1.25, 14.19642857, 1.346153846, 
    5.583333333, 2.8125, -2.097428958, 1.745602165, 3.531799729, 
    4.262516915, 1.826792963, 2.963464141, -2.963464141, -2.584573748, 
    -4.50608931, -4.912043302, -5.209742896, -6.211096076, -3.775372124, 
    -4.803788904, -8.944519621, -1.146245059, 2.938076416, 4.914361001, 
    5.12516469, 4.65085639, 1.567852437, -2.437417655, -3.544137022, 
    -4.677206851, -5.441370224, -6.442687747, -1.963109354, -3.675889328, 
    -7.891963109, -4.466403162), Criterion.Mean = c(162, 162, 
    162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 
    162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 
    162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 
    162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 
    162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 
    162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 
    162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 
    162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 
    162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 162, 79.4, 79.4, 
    79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 
    79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 
    79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4, 79.4)), row.names = c(NA, 
138L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### What I have done

First I have created a user defined function for calculating the SEE `SEE<- function(x){sqrt((sum(x)/(length(x)-2))^2)}`

I have then generated 1000 samples for each model, and for each sample I calculate the SEE. I used the `tapply` function as I needed to make sure that the SEE was calculated based on the residuals value that corresponded to a specific model. The code is below:

```
Bootstrapped_SEE<- tapply(new.meta$Residual, INDEX = new.meta$Model, FUN = function (x){
  int<- lapply(1:1000, function(i) sample(x, replace = T))
  Calc.SEE<- sapply(int, SEE)
})
```

This returns a list of length 21 (there are 21 models in the full dataset), where each element is length 1000 (1000 SEE values). To convert these to the SEE value I used the following code:

```
SEE.percentage.List<-lapply(SEE_Var_List, FUN = function(i) (i/new.meta$Crtierion.Mean)*100)
```

#### The problem

As I said above, what I want this to do is, for each element in the list (i.e., vector of SEE's corresponding to a particular model), divide by the criterion mean for the corresponding study (again there may be multiple models- and therefore list elements- per study, all of which have the same criterion mean). What is happening just now is that R is just cycling down the column vector `Criterion.Mean` and dividing the ith value. Good news? R works as it's supposed to! Bad news? After the 19th SEE Value, it begins to divide the SEE values which correspond to study 1, by study 2's `Criterion.Mean` value. So, what I need is a way to divide my SEE's values by the criterion mean values of a corresponding study, where there can be multiple models that for a given study (i.e, multiple elements of the list have the same criterion mean values).

#### The solution?

The conceptual solution is to somehow link each element of the list to a particular study, and then have code which divides all of elements which relate to the study by the corresponding `Criterion.Mean` value. I originally thought some sort of `tapply` function would work here, but then quickly realised that the list is independent to the dataframe containing and so supplying `study` as the index probably wouldn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this? I'm pretty lost as this exceeds my coding capabilities at present. I understand the problem and why it has happened, but I have no idea how to solve this syntactically. Thanks in advance for all of your help.

Comment: It seems like your problem is about applying a function along axes of a data frame, but you've tangled this simple question up in a much more complex context of your modelling. A minimal example would be better

Comment: On further inspection I see that you're not dealing with a data frame, but actually I think if you wrangle your data into one, it would be much clearer how to solve this problem.

Comment: Agreed! I did try to create a new dataframe with all of the information in one such that I had one dataframe with 3 columns, each of length 1000 (SEE values, relevant criterion mean values and I also added in a label to signify which model each value corresponded to, but I have still had no luck. No errors as such, but the output was wrong (as verified by manually calculating what I needed for each model). Model 2 output was 12 when it should be 1.119. 

Thank you for your suggestion though, I will keep wrangling and trying to see if I cannot come up with a neater set to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who follows this in the future, here's how I got round it using base R. I am aware there are likely solutions out there that are far more elegant and smooth, but this does the job:

**Verbal description of steps**

1. First, I created a new "subset" dataframe that contained only the model and it's respective *criterion mean* value once (i.e., I removed duplicate observations)
2. Next, I ordered the new dataframe by model, purely for ease of interpretation and checking. Because I was struggling so much to do this in a "loop" type manner, I went ahead and did it manually first. This ended up being a win in the end as it allowed me to cross-reference the results from my loop with the manual calculations to ensure they were correct... I just had to make sure the list elements corresponded to the right model (i.e., element 1= model 1).
3. I then used lapply to apply the `var` function to each element of the new list which contained the scaled SEE values.
4. Walla, you now have results. Is it pretty? Probably not. Could it be more elegant? Sure, it probably could. Does it work? Yes.

**CODE**

Here's the code I used:

```
#Create new dataframe, and remove duplicates.

  Temp_Dat<- full.data[!duplicated(full.data$Model), ]

#Order new dataframe by model 

  Temp_Dat<- Temp_Dat[order(Temp_Dat$Model), ]

#Create list to save results of for loop.
  
  Bootstrapped_SEE_Per <- list()
  
#Run for loop. [[i]] indicates sub-element of list and [i] indicates element of vector. Therefore this is applied to each sub-element of the list using the"ith" value in the criterion mean vector. This creates a new list, with the only change being that now all SEE values are scaled by criterion mean and expressed as a %

  for( i in 1:length(Bootstrapped_SEE)){
    Bootstrapped_SEE_Per[[i]] <- (Bootstrapped_SEE[[i]]/ Temp_Dat$Criterion.Mean[i])*100
  }

#Use lapply function to calculate the variance of each element of the new list.
  
  SEE_Per_Variance<- lapply(Bootstrapped_SEE_Per, var)
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in a similar boat at some-point in the future. For those reading this that use `tidyverse` I believe you that you might be able to  use the `map2` function from the `purr` package. However, I am pretty unfamiliar with `tidyverse` as a whole, so I opted for a base R solution.

Thanks to all that contributed!